# Coderush v11.1.6 Code Formatting

Tags: coderush

i am evaluating the new wrapping/alignment feature of Code Formatting.

Is is possible to wrap the code only if it exceeds let's say 120 characters.

The option "Wrap long lines" is set to 120 but it seems not to work.

PS. I am coming from the resharper camp, but it is so painfully slow on large projects that i need to search for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Wrap long lines" option wraps  code lines whose length exceeds the option value. However, in the current implementation it doesn't wrap statements. This means that it will wrap long conditions, identifiers with a long name, etc but not the statements that are located on a single line. The good news is that the next major version of CodeRush will allow you to wrap any code that exceeds the option value (e.g. 120 characters). To make the current option work, toggle the "Wrap long lines" option on and set the column's size to your preferred value. Then, go to the General Formatting options and enable the "Adjust code style on autoformat" option - this will allow you to reformat the code with the "Wrap long lines" option in action using the Visual Studio formatting (e.g. Edit->Advanced->Format Document, CTRL+E,D).